# How do webpack pre-loaders work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm building a node app and I'm using webpack to process my client side scripts. I'm using webpack node api and on my app bootstrap file I simply do this:

```
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js')

    webpack(webpackConfig, (err, stats) => {
        if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
           //do something with that
        }
    })
```

This works well until I try to write with ES6 syntax. Although I have defined in my `webpack.config.js` that babel should be used to pre-process the files it simply doesn't work. It says that there is a syntax error.

this is my `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./resources/assets/js/main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/build",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use : {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            "es2015",
                            "es2016",
                            "stage-2"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

this is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "topo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node app test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta11",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "António Quadrado",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I found multiple problems regarding webpack and ES6 with babel and I tried to work it out with the solutions that were given on those situations but I failed to make it work and that's why I posting my specific case, hoping that someone can point me to my error.

I'm not just looking for the solution to this particular problem but also to understand how the webpack and its pre-loaders work so I can avoid situations like this in the future.

I'm using node v7.8.0

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you testing for `.js` and not `.es6` file extension?

Comment: I'm not aware of the `.es6` extension. I have just `.js` files that have ES6 syntax written on them. Also, I did it like it was on webpack docs. Didn't see any reference to `.es6` files. Can you explain?

Comment: `.es6` is used by some people, but it's relatively uncommon. Since we're way passes ES6 at this point, with ES8 almost published, tying your JS version to a file extension is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`use`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-use) expects an array of loaders to use for a particular rule. Since you only have a single loader in your rule, you should just put all of the loader properties directly inside that rule (dropping `use` entirely):

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    options: {
      presets: [
        "es2015",
        "es2016",
        "stage-2"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

If you had to use `use`, it would look like this instead:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: [
            "es2015",
            "es2016",
            "stage-2"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the problem. I've tried both ways and it's spitting the same  syntax error that disappears as soon as I drop the `import xis from '/xis.js'`

Comment: I must apologize since you were right. I had a syntax error elsewhere, I fixed and it now works.